# match_parent in parent with minWidth results in zero width child

Tags: android, layout

When I have a `FrameLayout` that uses a `minWidth` and then I place an `ImageView` into it with `match_parent`, the resulting width is 0.

See this layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout // is width 100 from minWidth
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="#FF0000">

        <ImageView // should be width 80, but is 0. Why?
            android:id="@+id/child"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="#FFFF00"/>
    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I would expect the view to look like this:

[image]

But what I get is an `ImageView` with a 0 width:

[image]

Any idea what is going on and how I can have `child` take up the whole width of `parent` in this case?

Edit:
Adding an image to the `ImageView` does not fix the issue, it just sets the child width to the image size.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to set **`android:adjustViewBounds="true"`** in your `ImageView`

```
    <ImageView
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/...."
```

[image]

Please note that `adjustViewBounds` will **not** increase the size of the `ImageView` beyond the natural dimensions of the drawable.

Comment: This is just a test layout, in the real app the image would be loaded and set at runtime. That's why I didn't set it here. But even setting one does not fix the issue. It just set's the `ImageView`'s width to the image width. I'll add this to the question.

Comment: @SimonSays Sorry my bad. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Gabriel. I've played around with `adjustViewBounds` before. It works as long as the image and the enclosing `FrameLayout` have the same width/height ratio. If not, then the `ImageView` still does not fill the whole available space. Also I feel like it should work without even loading an image, but with this solution it does not.